# Add Div Text code inline to onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div where I would like to get the value and use it inside an onclick event.

Here's the div.

```
<div id="cars">100</div>
```

Then I need to enter the id cars text or html into the message below.

So I need to insert the 100 where is said INSERT HERE in the code below.

```
<img onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message: Hello  INSERT HERE')" src="images/share_text.png" style="height:2em" />
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('cars').innerHTML
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#cars').text()
```

Comment: Nice that you demonstrated both ways.  One is just 40 bytes and the other evil way over [80000 bytes](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/05/jquery-library-file-size-over-years.html)

Answer (score 3):

This will be very simple using **jquery**

```
$("#cars").text();
```

Will give you the text

Answer (score 1):

If you want the jQuery solution use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the text between the start/close div tags.

```
<img onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message: Hello' + $('#cars').html())" src="images/share_text.png" style="height:2em" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not suggested to include jquery/ javascript code in html code. I suggest you can do this on document.ready event as below, you need to give an "id" to your image tag also.

HTML code (add id to image tag)

```
<div id="cars">100</div>
<img onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message: Hello  INSERT HERE')" src="images/share_text.png" style="height:2em" id="image_id" />
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var car_val = $("#cars").html(); 
    var onclick_Val = $("#image_id").attr("onclick");
    var onclick_new_val = onclick_Val.replace('INSERT HERE', car_val);
    $("#image_id").attr( 'onclick', onclick_new_val ); 
 });
```